# Why does Jhipster gateway forward request without access token to microservice api?

Tags: oauth-2.0, microservices, jhipster

I have generated a microservice application using Jhipster. I have also generated a Eureka registry, Zuul gateway and UAA server for authentication (using Oauth2). I would like to use authentication using grant type 'password' where the client sends a username, password in request and gets an access token in return which is to be used for subsequent interactions.

I am able to get all things up and running and also create a user and get his access token. But when I send any request to the microservice API without any access token, the gateway processes (runs some filters) and forwards the request to the microservice API. I was expecting it to return a 403 error saying authentication required. 
While debugging I see there is a spring 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter' that runs and blocks any requests with expired tokens but if no token is present, it allows the request to pass and it hits the microservice api.

I am confused about this, does it mean that we need to write custom code to get oauth2 working with Jhipster? Should I write my own filter for this that will check for access token and validate with UAA? Going through Jhipster documents I got an impression that it should work out of the box. I do not have experience with Spring security or Jhipster so apologies if this is a stupid question.

Comment: UAA uses cookies for auth by default.  Are you sure you aren't sending a cookie in your request?  I just tested and with the cookie, the request to a microservice returns 200, without the cookie returns a 401.  If you changed or customized the code to get the access token, please add it to your question.

Comment: Jon, I havent done any customization. Just generated the code and bring up the 4 services. I am not sending any cookies too. Infact, if I send the request without creating any users and login at all, it still hits the microservice. This makes me suspect if I am missing any configuration after code generation by Jhipster? If possible can you tell me which filter in your case returns the 401?

Comment: I was missing security configuration - I needed to configure the microservice api  path for security in SecurityConfiguration file.